# Getting Linking undefined even if linked correctly

Tags: ios, react-native

I 'm getting `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.Linking.canOpenURL')` when trying to use Linking on iOS. I've tried with both `LinkingIOS` and `Linking` but it crashes the same way.

```
    var url = 'http://maps.apple.com/?ll=48.2292016,-1.5300695';

    console.log(url);

    Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {

        if (supported) {

            Linking.openURL(url);

            this.props.navigator.popToTop();

        } else {

            console.warn('Don\'t know how to go');
        }

    }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

I have checked if LinkingIOS is correctly linked and it is the case. I've even re-linked it, restarted both xcode and the simulator but I'm still getting this error.

I do have `RTCLinking.xcodeproj` in my `Libraries` folder and I do have `libRTCLinking.a` in my linked binaries.

Why the h$$$ is it still crashing?

Comment: Came across this in the docs, have you done it? "NOTE: As of iOS 9, your app needs to provide the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key inside Info.plist or canOpenURL will always return false."

Comment: In my case, `Linking` is undefined. This is the problem but I do not know why.

Comment: `import { View, StyleSheet, Linking } from 'react-native'` is this kinda how you have it? Make sure you're not importing from 'react' and its 'react-native'

Comment: Arrr, @MattAft that was the problem, I was importing from 'react' instead of 'react-native'. I can't believe I've lost time on that issue...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. the problem was IDE auto imported a Linking as this

```
import * as  from "react-native-web";
```

But it should be this !

```
import Linking from "react-native";
```

or you can input as
in my app.js

```
import { Button,Text,View,Linking} from "react-native";
```

Hope this helps some one